# How to create a gitflow release with Pull Requests?

Tags: git, git-flow

Usually the checklist for a gitflow release would be something like:

- Create release branch off develop
- Merge release branch into master
- Merge release branch into develop

I would like to introduce pull requests for each release, but I wonder how to handle merge conflicts, especially when merging `release/*` into master.
Right now I am doing the following:

- Create release branch off `develop` (`release/x`)
- Create a PR from `release/x` into `develop`
- Create a "target" branch off `master` (let's call it `release/X-target`)
- Merge `release/x` into `release/x-target` (`git merge -X theirs release/x`)
- Create a PR from `release/x-target` into `master`

Would this be the right way to handle gitflow releases with PRs?